# Unable to change timezone from EST

Tags: datetime, python-2.6

I'm not sure what is wrong in below code. Can someone please guide.

```
from datetime import datetime
time = 'Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031'
dt = datetime.strptime(time,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
print dt
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only timezones that `strptime` recognizes are UTC, GMT and whatever is returned by `time.tzname`. It seems however that even when you supply one of those, the time zone information is discarded.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue22426